Python process OOM killed on Vertex AI despite low data size
I'm running a Python process (making some predictions with an LSTM model that I trained on my local machine) on a Vertex AI instance (c3-highmem-22, 176 GB RAM) in Google Cloud Platform that involves manipulating a 3.5GB dataset being brought into memory from BigQuery.
The process works fine on my local machine with only 32GB RAM, but on Vertex AI - even with a 176gb RAM instance - it gets terminated due to an Out-of-Memory (OOM) error.
Here's the relevant part of the error message from the logs:
2024-04-10 15:27:59.992 BST
[  672.752608] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=jupyter.service,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/jupyter.service,task=python,pid=3740,uid=1000\r\n
2024-04-10 15:28:00.043 BST
[  672.769191] Out of memory: Killed process 3740 (python) total-vm:211774876kB, anon-rss:179645328kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:354232kB oom_score_adj:0\r\n
2024-04-10 15:28:00.043 BST
Apr 10 14:27:59 instance-20240410-151420 kernel: [  672.119856] python invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x100dca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE|__GFP_ZERO), order=0, oom_score_adj=0\r\n
2024-04-10 15:28:00.093 BST
Apr 10 14:28:00 instance-20240410-151420 kernel: [  672.130423] CPU: 8 PID: 4164 Comm: python Not tainted 5.10.0-28-cloud-amd64 #1 Debian 5.10.209-2\r\n
2024-04-10 15:28:00.093 BST
Apr 10 14:28:00 instance-20240410-151420 kernel: [  672.139309] Hardware name: Google Google Compute Engine/Google Compute Engine, BIOS Google 03/29/2024\r\n

Here's the bit of code that causes the kernel to break unexpectedly:
# Start timing
start_time_predictions = time.time()

# Prepare data as a TensorFlow tensor
data_tensor = tf.constant(data_3d_test, dtype=tf.float32)

# Use the serving signature for prediction.
predictions = model.signatures['serving_default'](lstm_input=data_tensor)['output_0']

# Convert predictions to numpy
predictions_np = predictions.numpy()

# Ensure predictions are shaped as expected
assert predictions_np.shape[1] == 26, "Each title should have 26 predictions"

# End timing
end_time_predictions = time.time()

# Calculate and print the prediction time
predictions_time = end_time_predictions - start_time_predictions
# `format_time` is a function to format the time string
formatted_time = format_time(predictions_time)
print(f"Time taken to generate predictions: {formatted_time}")

I tried increasing the memory of the instances. Same issue.
I expected the model to start making predictions like it does when I run the code on my local machine and it runs fine.
For context, I'm moving from running my model predictions to Vertex AI to set up automatic runs of the code each week and so it can be managed in the Cloud instead of locally.
